# Valid circuit to drop voltage?

Tags: circuit-design, voltage

I needed to drop the voltage(5V -> 4,2V) for a small IC(consumes ~2A peak), and used what I could find laying around.
Is this a valid way for dropping the voltage? The resistor turns very hot, but perhaps that is expected?

If I were to re-do it with out limitations in components, what would be the best approach?

[image]

Comment: 2A LDO regulator would be my suggestion.

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? You can likely do without the resistor as long as your IC is drawing a very small amount of current, or at least make the resistor ~200 ohm or more. An LDO would be better though.

Comment: How about two diodes in parallel (opposite polarity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a perfectly "valid" way to do it, but it's probably a bad idea.

First, 4.2 volts across a 36 ohm resistor will draw about .12 amps, and the resistor will dissipate almost exactly 1/2 watt. If your resistor is getting very hot, it means that it's not rated for this power. A 1-watt resistor would appropriate.

Second, if the load can draw up to 2 amps, an increase of .12 amps will probably not overstress the power supply. That's only an increase of about 5%.

Third, you really need to check how the diode responds when the load (not just the 36 ohm resistor) is connected. Are  you sure the diode is rated for a constant 2+ amps? It may well get very hot and/or fail.

Finally, the load voltage will change somewhat as the load current varies (if it does). However, the voltage across D1 won't change a whole lot. Much will depend on whether the intended load has wildly varying current (less than 2 amps, of course), and depends on the power supply to stay constant.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid with 1N4007. [Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28002.pdf) of 1N4007 states Average Rectified Output Current as 1A. If your IC consumes 2A longer than a few ms, diode gets hot, maybe it burns. It's better to use a diode with higher current rate.

Also, 2A can be high for direct heat dissipation. If you have no size or BOM restrictions, you can use a voltage regulator.